# IE10 removes padding on input with right alignment

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I've come across some IE10 wierdness regarding padding in a right aligned inputfield.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fhWhn/

```
::-ms-clear, ::-ms-clear{
    display: none;
}
```

This removes the "IE10 icons" but what do I do if I want to keep these and keep my padding?
Is there another, smarter, way of keeping the padding after onblur?

Answer (score 5):

I ran in to this same problem.  To get padding back, just set the value of the textbox on blur.

My simple solution:

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function (evt){
    var $element = $(this);
    $element.val($element.val());
});
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, the "x" icon only seems to appear in textboxes with widths greater or equal than 60 pixels, however there is a different padding issue in textboxes sub 60px wide.  Fortunately I was able to increase my textbox width to 60px and not have to figure that one out.

Comment: Note this interferes with the raising of the 'change' event for the input: focus the input, change the value, and select another application (i.e. lose focus on IE without losing focus on the input within IE) - this raises the 'blur' event and the above code removes the record that there is a 'pending change'; return focus to IE and lose focus on the input - you have now changed the value without a change event firing.

Answer (score 5):

A possible workaround is to use the style `direction: rtl;` on your input, which will move the **`×`** to the left-hand side of the element. However, the behavior of using right-to-left may not be ideal for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Eric's solution worked for me and is much nicer, but I'm leaving this answer here in case some future version of IE needs a different fix

New IE, New IE-specific rendering issues...

I've been debugging the same behaviour. The only thing I've found that works so far is:

1. Removing focus from the input (even explicitly setting the “padding-right” per element has no effect while it has focus)
2. Setting the padding-right value to a *different* value to the correct value (setting it to the correct value triggers no change, presumably because the layout system knows the computed CSS value hasn’t changed so decides no re-draw is necessary)
3. Waiting for a re-draw (instantly – or even after a timeout of 1 or 2 milliseconds - setting the property again to the correct value results in no change, presumably because no re-draw has taken place as per above)
4. Setting the property to the correct value (e.g. using `$this.css("padding-right", "")`, which removes any per-element value and allows the computed CSS value to take over).

However this is of course undesirable as it involves removing focus from the input when the user may be in the middle of typing.

Answer (score 0):

JustinStolle's answer is the best approach, I think.

Example:

```
input[type="text"].field-al-right{
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you try adding 'box-sizing' to your css?

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```